# How to make a SwiftUI view scrollable so that it doesn't overlap with tab bar?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

So in my app I have a view that looks like this

[image]

But if you add a link to video a video player appears and so the tab bar overlaps the form.
[image]

How do I make the view scrollable so that I can scroll to the bottom of the form?
Putting it in a ScrollView for some reason just makes the form disappear.

Here is the code for the view:

```swift
VStack {
    if let image = self.image {
        Image(uiImage: image)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .padding()
            .onTapGesture {
                isIamgePickerShown = true
            }
    } else {
        Image(systemName: "shippingbox.fill")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .padding()
            .onTapGesture {
                isIamgePickerShown = true
            }
    }
    VStack{
        if !video.isEmpty {
            YouTubeVideoView(videoID: $video)
                .frame(maxHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.3)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .padding()
        }
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                Picker("Category", selection: $category) {
                    Text("Food").tag("Food")
                    Text("Tools").tag("Tools")
                    Text("Books").tag("Books")
                }
                        
                DecimalField(value: $amount)
                        
                DatePicker("Last Update", selection: $lastUpdated)
                        
                TextField("Video URL", text: $video)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Form is scrollable actually, so needed your minimal reproducible example to investigate the behaviour.

Comment: Try using a `ScrollView` wrapping the whole `VStack` instead of wrapping just the `Form` .

Comment: When I rebuild it the lower part is scrollable. If you want the video to scroll too, follow @HunterLion 's remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way for you:

```
VStack {
    if let image = self.image {
        Image(uiImage: image)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .padding()
            .onTapGesture {
                isIamgePickerShown = true
            }
    } else {
        Image(systemName: "shippingbox.fill")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .padding()
            .onTapGesture {
                isIamgePickerShown = true
            }
    }
    VStack{

        Form {

        if !video.isEmpty {
            YouTubeVideoView(videoID: $video)
                .frame(maxHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.3)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .padding()
        }

            Section {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                Picker("Category", selection: $category) {
                    Text("Food").tag("Food")
                    Text("Tools").tag("Tools")
                    Text("Books").tag("Books")
                }
                        
                DecimalField(value: $amount)
                        
                DatePicker("Last Update", selection: $lastUpdated)
                        
                TextField("Video URL", text: $video)
            }
        }
    }
}
```